# How to create a people picker in my visual webpart via javascript,sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have a field in my webpart

[image]

it is a div element.

I have tried some solution like 
[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713593.aspx) but it was useless.

how can I make it with javascript?

thanks

Comment: are you using JQuery in your solution?

Comment: no but I can use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using this in one of my solutions and it ofcourse depends on JQuery to work.

**Step 1** - Load this code on the page where your people picker div is

```
(function ($) {

    RegisterScriptFiles('clienttemplates.js');
    RegisterScriptFiles('clientforms.js');
    RegisterScriptFiles('clientpeoplepicker.js');
    RegisterScriptFiles('autofill.js');

    function RegisterScriptFiles(filename) {
        var scriptEle = document.createElement('script');
        scriptEle.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
        scriptEle.setAttribute("src", "/_layouts/15/" + filename);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptEle)

    }
    // Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.
    function initializePeoplePicker(eleId) {
        // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
        var schema = {};
        schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
        schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
        schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
        schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
        schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
        schema['Width'] = '63%';
        // Render and initialize the picker. 
        // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
        // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
        // picker properties.
        this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(eleId, null, schema);
    }

    function GetPeoplePickerValues(eleId) {
        var toSpanKey = eleId + "_TopSpan";
        var peoplePicker = null;

        // Get the people picker object from the page.
        //var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
        var ClientPickerDict = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict;
        // Get the people picker object from the page.
        for (var propertyName in ClientPickerDict) {
            if (propertyName == toSpanKey) {
                peoplePicker = ClientPickerDict[propertyName];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (peoplePicker != null) {
            // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                userInfo += user['DisplayText'] + ";#";
            }
            return userInfo;
        }
        else
            return '';
    }

    $.fn.spPeoplePicker = function () {
        var eleId = $(this).attr('id');
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { initializePeoplePicker(eleId); }, 'sp.core.js');
    };

    // Query the picker for user information.
    $.fn.getUserInfo = function () {
        var eleId = $(this).attr('id');
        var spUsersInfo = GetPeoplePickerValues(eleId);
        return spUsersInfo.slice(0, -2);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

**Step 2** Initialise the people picker as below:

```
 $("#peoplePickerDivIDHere").spPeoplePicker();
```

Comment: It is working now but I have also enabled `'AllowMultipleValues'`  but I cannot store more than 1 item in my list i.e If I have 2 persons in my list it adds only one person. How to add all selected persons ?

Comment: is your list field configured to accept mulitple values?

Comment: Thanks bro this solved my problem however I came here one year later but better late than never :)